# Robolectric error org.fest.reflect.exception.ReflectionError: Unable to find method '$$robo$getData'

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, junit, robolectric

When i am wrtting

```
@Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
       Activity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(ActivityMain.class).create().get();

    }
```

and after running the test Its giving me error `org.fest.reflect.exception.ReflectionError: Unable to find method '$$robo$getData'` I am using `eclipse` and ant build for testing the `robolectric` test for `android`.

But this code is working fine with my test

```
@Test
    public void testBasicResourceValue() throws Exception {
        String helloFromActivity = new ActivityMain().getResources().getString(R.string.str_my_file);
       assertThat(helloFromActivity, equalTo("newfile"));
    }
```

so its confirmed that the program is able to get the `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Activity activity =
>   Robolectric.buildActivity(ActivityMain.class).create().get(); this
>   line is not working with ANT build i dont know why? i heard
>   robolectric is stopped supporting ANT.So i found a another workaround
>   for this problem to get the shadow object of the activity by using
>   this code given below

```
 @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
      MyActivity  activity = new MyActivity();
      //Remember setContentView() has to call before you are trying to get any resource ID from the activity like Button,TextView etc other wise you will get the not shadow object for those views.
        activity.setContentView(R.layout.warning);
        Assert.assertNotNull(activity);

    }
```